# PowerShell new-partition complains about DriveLetter argument

Tags: powershell

Here's my powerShell "piped" command

```
Get-Disk |
Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' |
Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru |
New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter Z |
Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "ephemeral" -Confirm:$false
```

It complains about the `DriveLetter` parameter.

> New-Partition : Invalid Parameter Activity ID:
>   {e3ec7f8a-a672-4c81-a149-9440244ca230} At line:7 char:1
>   + New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter "Z" |
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_Disk) [New-Partition],
>   CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 5,New-Partition

The following script without it works just fine. I'm out of ideas...

```
Get-Disk |
Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' |
Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru |
New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize |
Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "ephemeral" -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: OK seems like you can't use `DriveLetter` and `AssignDriveLetter` at the same time, [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/new-partition?view=win10-ps) are very unclear about this.

It should be

```
New-Partition -UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter Z |
```

Comment: I created an issue on their GitHub repo to fix this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-powershell-docs/issues/1230