# PowerShell launching multiple sub processes and going to hung state

Tags: powershell

What is wrong with the below PowerShell script?

```
#powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\newdisk.ps1
$rawdisk = Get-Disk | Where-Object partitionstyle -eq ‘raw’
$driveletter = ''
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\newdisk.ps1

function preparedisk ($driveletter) {
    Get-Disk |
        Where-Object partitionstyle -eq ‘raw’ |
        Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT -PassThru |
        New-Partition -DiskNumber 1 -AssignDriveLetter -DriveLetter '$driveletter' -UseMaximumSize |
        Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel “VOL01” -Confirm:$false
}

if (!(Test-Path E:)) { 
    'E do not exist'
    $driveletter = 'E'   
} elseif (!(Test-Path F:)) { 
    'E do not exist' 
    $driveletter = 'F'
} else { 
    'Please the disk'
    exit 4
}

if ($rawdisk.Count -eq 1) {
    "Raw Disk Available,drive letter set to $driveletter"
    preparedisk $driveletter
} else {
    "Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to $driveletter"
    exit 5
}
```

When I run the below block individually it works without any issue.

```
Get-Disk |
    Where-Object partitionstyle -eq ‘raw’ |
    Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT -PassThru |
    New-Partition -DiskNumber 1 -AssignDriveLetter -DriveLetter '$driveletter' -UseMaximumSize |
    Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel “VOL01” -Confirm:$false
```

Basically I am trying to find unassigned drive letters and assign it the new volume after attaching the new disk to the computer.

When the run the script it is launching multiple sub processes and finally failing. When I ran the below command, it actually worked without issues, not sure what is the issue here.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\newdisk.ps1
Thread failed to start.
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
E do not exist
Raw Disk not available,drive letter set to E
```

Comment: **_[1]_** this >>> `'$driveletter'  <<< means your variable is NOT being expanded - it will be treated literally as `$driveletter` due to the single quotes. **_[2]_** why are you calling a script via `powershell -Execut...` when you could probably just dot source it into your current script? **_[3]_** what does that other script do? **_[4]_** you have typographic quotes [curly quotes] in your code. that is known to cause strange problems ... so you likely otta replace them with straight quotes.

Comment: This is my first script. 1) I forgot to change it in the question,but i did made the change. 2) i am using it since i have not set Set-ExecutionPolicy to unrestricted, i did it now. 3) basically if i run the block as a single command,i.e without the if condition, it runs and without any error and creates drive. 4) i am not sure which ones are you referring to , function or if statements ? . I am following the syntax from the documentation. But besides all of these i don't understand why the codes runs like for loop ? actually not loop, its launching multiple sub process and finally crashing.

Comment: thank you for the info! [*grin*] **_typographic quotes_** are the ones like those at the end of the `$rawdisk =` line. the word `raw` is enclosed in typographic - not straight - quotes.

Comment: PLEASE fix your displayed code to match what you are actually running. from your answer to my pint #2, this line >>> `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ...` <<< is apparently not actually in your code.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i got it now ..  ``` powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\newdisk.ps1 ```

Comment: if your posted code is the real code you are running ... then the **_recursive call to the same script from inside the script is your problem_**.

Comment: it is what happens, its the same script i copied it calling in in a loop.

Comment: your script contains this line >>> `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\newdisk.ps1` <<< if that is the name of the script ... then it is calling ITSELF and that is what causes your loop. ///// if the script you have posted IS NOT THE ONE YOU ARE RUNNING ... then **_post the script you are running_**.

Comment: Thanks Lee , my script is running now. Beside the things you pointed out. i am also facing the below issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929179/powershell-new-partition-complains-about-driveletter-argument?rq=1   this is resolved.

Comment: glad to know that you got it working. [*grin*] ///// as for the problem you linked to ... the two driveletter parameters are exclusive - only one can be used. the `Assign` one auto-assigns the letter, the other allows one to specify the letter.